# How to downgrade this piece of code from .net 4.0 to 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I've been really loving this extension method in my .NET 4.0 code:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Now, I'd really like to use it in my .net 3.5 project, but it's missing the Contains method.  How can I cleanly downgrade this extension method without complicating things too much?

Comment: That code compiles for me in .net 3.5. Do you have a using for `System.Linq`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contains is an extension on IEnumerable introduced in 3.5 as part of LINQ.  This code will compile under 3.5.

If it's not then make sure you have included

```
using System.Linq
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with James Gaunt, this should run under 3.5 as is.

Perhaps you have neglected to add the `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;` declarations at the top of your code?

I get caught by that all the time.

Comment: This code doesn't need System.Collections.Generic.  Generic parameters are supported natively by the complier - no libraries included.  It just needs System - for the exception - and System.Linq.